# Ninject binding for a type which requires the current Request.Url

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I am using Ninject 3 in an MVC5-based website, and trying to work out how to get DI to work with a type that tests properties of a `Uri.Host` value passed into its constructor. I'd like the binding to somehow provide the current URL. The minimal structure I've tried initially is:

```
public class StructuredUrlTester : IStructuredUrlTester
{
    // Expose public getters for parts of the uri.Host value
    bool MyBooleanProperty { get; private set; }

    public StructuredUrlTester(Uri uri)
    {
        // Test the value of uri.Host and extract parts via regex
    }
}

// In Global.asax.cs
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        kernel.Bind<IStructuredUrlTester>()
            .To<StructuredUrlTester>()
            .InTransientScope();
            .WithConstructorArgument("uri", Request.Url);
    }
}

// In MyController.cs
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStructuredUrlTester _tester;

    public ContentPageController(IStructuredUrlTester tester)
    {
        this._tester = tester;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string viewName = "DefaultView";
        if (this._tester.MyBooleanProperty)
        {
            viewName = "CustomView";
        }

        return View(viewName);
    }
}
```

As the `CreateKernel()` call happens before the `Request` object is available, the `.WithConstructorArgument()` part throws an exception ("System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context").

How can I provide the binding of interface to concrete type, whilst also being able to provide the e.g. `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` value (available within the Controller) to the constructor of the concrete type, at run-time when it's available?

Comment: wrap the httpcontext in an abstraction.

Comment: Have you considered getting uri from here System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, inside the constructor of StructuredUrlTester

Comment: Is there a clear reason why do you need to implement this logic behind and abstraction? Plainly I would just put it to a helper/extension method...

Comment: Dima and kayess: Whilst in this case I need to pass in the current URL, I don't want to the StructuredUrlTester to depend on knowing the current HttpContext etc. It should just take a `System.Uri` object and expose properties depending on its structure. I may wish to swap out that concrete type for some other concrete mechanism of testing later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the desired functionality in an abstraction:

```
public interface IUriProvider {
    Uri Current { get; }
}
```

Refactor the tester class:

```
public class StructuredUrlTester : IStructuredUrlTester {
    // Expose public getters for parts of the uri.Host value
    bool MyBooleanProperty { get; private set; }

    public StructuredUrlTester(IUriProvider provider) {
        Uri uri = provider.Current;
        // Test the value of uri.Host and extract parts via regex
    }
}
```

The provider implementation should wrap the `Request.Url`:

```
public class UriProvider : IUriProvider {
    public Uri Current { get { return  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url; } }
}
```

And note that the `Current` property should actually be called within the action of a controller where `HttpContext` and its request are available.

Comment: Absolutely great, worked just as I needed. I can see now how using the provider means that the `HttpContext` isn't accessed until `MyController` is being constructed (which through Ninject means the `StructuredUrlTester` is also being constructed), at which time the Request object has been populated and is available. Thank you for your help!